# Is there an \iftex4ht command, and if not, how should it be defined?

Tags: conditionals, tex4ht

Background: I'm using TikZ to generate a load of pictures that I want to put on the web as SVGs.  So I'm using the `pgfsys-tex4ht.def` driver and it's working very well.  My gut feeling is that the SVG output from TikZ/pgf is "experimental" so while designing the pictures, I'm not using a special driver but just generating the PDFs via pdflatex.  Also, I want PDFs as well as SVGs at the end.

So rather than having to comment out the line

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
```

each time, I'd rather have a switch that loaded it if `tex4ht` was loaded; that is, I *already* specify the output when I decide whether to run `pdflatex` or `htlatex` - I don't want to have to specify it twice.  So, my question:

> Is there an `\iftex4ht` somewhat akin to the `\ifpdf` provided by `ifpdf.sty`?
>   If not, what would be the "right" way to test for the presence of `tex4ht`?

Comment: Well, you know that Tex4ht will fail the \ifpdf test, so since you seem to generate your output with either pdflatex or htlatex...

Comment: @Charles: yes, that did occur to me, but I don't like testing an absence - it doesn't feel safe to me.  What if one day I go mad and use plain old latex?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is always this:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{LOADED}{NOT LOADED}
```

Suitable for other packages of interest as well, of course. (Usual caveats about @ character apply.)

Comment: This gives false negative if *package* `tex4ht` is not explicitly loaded but we are running `tex4ht` from the command-line (say: `mk4ht oolatex`).  Maybe your approach should be combined with Nasser's approach below: `\ifdefined\HCode`, in a disjunction of conditions that defines another condition `\ifhtlatex`.

Answer (score 14):

A conditional named `\iftex4ht` is impossible to define without side effects. However using directly `\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}` has a big limitation, because it's allowed only in the preamble.

There are a few strategies to circumvent the problem: all use `\@ifpackageloaded` in the preamble to define something that one will be able to use also in the body of the document.

1. **Primitive conditional syntax**

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}
     {\let\iftexforht\iftrue}
     {\let\iftexforht\iffalse}
   \makeatother
   ```

   and use `\iftexforht` just like any of the primitive conditionals.
2. **LaTeX pseudoconditional**

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}
     {\let\iftexforhtTF\@firstoftwo}
     {\let\iftexforhtTF\@secondoftwo}
   \makeatother
   ```

   to be used like

   ```
   \iftexforhtTF{<code for TeX4ht>}{<code when TeX4ht isn't used>}
   ```
3. **Almost like a primitive conditional**

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \edef\texforht{TT\noexpand\fi
     \@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}
       {\noexpand\iftrue}
       {\noexpand\iffalse}}
   \makeatother
   ```

   to be used as

   ```
   \if\texforht
     <code for TeX4ht>
   \else
     <code when TeX4ht isn't used>
   \fi
   ```

Which one to prefer is a matter of taste. Both the first and third methods allow conditional nesting.

---

Prompted by [extra \fi error when using \localtableofcontents inside an \if...\else..\fi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220718/extra-fi-error-when-using-localtableofcontents-inside-an-if-else-fi), there is another reason for using the LaTeX conditional style (case 2 in the list above).

When used in the preamble, a construction such as

```
\iftexforht
  <code for TeX4ht case>
\else
  <code for non TeX4ht case>
\fi
```

is usually good and practical. However when used in the document body, you can incur in problems. For instance, if you have

```
\iftexforht\else\localtableofcontents\fi
```

as in the linked question, this won't work and throw a mysterious error message, because of how `\localtableofcontents` is defined. Instead,

```
\iftexforhtTF{}{\localtableofcontents}
```

would have worked properly.

The `\iftexforhtTF` macro can be defined either with the code above or, with Nasser's idea,

```
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\HCode
   \let\iftexforhtTF\@firstoftwo
\else
   \let\iftexforhtTF\@secondoftwo
\fi
\makeatother
```

Credit to karlkoeller for spotting the problem in the linked question.

Comment: `\ltx@ifpackageloaded` of package `ltxcmds` can also be used in the document body and does not have the restriction that it can only be used as preamble command.

Answer (score 5):

Based on Harald's answer you can define your `\iftex4ht` as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tex4ht}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{\def\iftex4ht{\iftrue}}
                         {\def\iftex4ht{\iffalse}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\iftex4ht TeX4ht\else no!\fi
\end{document}
```

OK, this answer is kind of a joke, but I wanted to point out that you can't use `\newif\iftex4ht` or `\newcommand\iftex4ht` since `4` is not letter. With `\def` it works (delimited macro with no arguments), but you can't nest it in other `\if`s since TeX doesn't see that it's an `\if`.

Comment: `\catcode`\``\4=11`

Comment: @Charles: Well, of course you can do that. But then you might run into trouble somewhere else, e.g. when there's some `\frac45`. And you don't want to set the catcode before each call of `\iftex4ht` ...

Comment: I was continuing the joke, but, you know, you could define a convenient `\four` macro...

Comment: @Charles: OK, sorry, I took that seriouly. Now with `\four` I did get it ...