# Why was a lion chosen as LaTeX mascot?

Tags: tex-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does TeX have a lion as mascot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49087/why-does-tex-have-a-lion-as-mascot)

What was the motivation for choosing a lion as mascot for LaTeX?

(Sorry, for not providing an MWE for this question.)

Comment: I was fond of ducks before it was mainstream. `:P`

Answer (score 2):

The drawings in Knuth's TeXbook are from Duane Bibby. According to [this interview](https://www.tug.org/interviews/bibby.html) Duane chose the Lion as the theme for the book.