# TeX Lion logos and others

Tags: logos

Is there any compilation of TeX Lion (colored or monochrome)?

I know the Lion in http://www.ctan.org/lion/. But I have already seen some nice (and colored) logos here, for TeX talks or interviews. It would be nice to have a compilation of them.

Moreover, is there any other (La)TeX logos that can be used?

Comment: Sort of related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-parentheses-or-any-other-tex-related-logo

Comment: More or less, yes. But I am more interested in pictures.

Comment: on linux `texdoc lion` shows up a running TeX lion similar on the front page of LaTeX Tutorials A primer by Indian TeX Users Group. related one [Why does TeX have a lion as mascot?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49087/why-does-tex-have-a-lion-as-mascot)

Answer (score 2):

Some pictures of TeX lions can be found by [Google Image](https://www.google.de/search?tbm=isch&q=%22tex%20lion%22&oq=%22tex%20lion%22) search for `"tex lion"`. But I'm not shure about the licenses of these, a topic you should concerne when using them.

The lion also is the most common symbol for the TeX world. So I'm not shure if there are any other logos beside the textual ones mentioned by @Torbjørn T.

Comment: This is not exactly the answer I was looking for. I think it would be nice to have a kind of package with that logos (that could also have typewriting text logos: Metapost, LateX, TeX, ConTeXt, etc.).

Comment: I don't know if there's a package combining that but I've never heard about one. If you need this just on your own, I'd define some macros on my own for this (e.g. `\newcommand\lion[1]{\includegraphics[#1]{lion}}`). To make it a public package you need all those "lion icons" being licensed under a certain license (LPPL) which could be difficult if you don't create them on your own and the original creator doesn't release them under this lincese.

Comment: To get the text logos please have a look to `dtklogos` or `hologo` packages. If you create a package, you could maybe use those.