# Error when compiling with Tex4ht

Tags: subfloats, tex4ht

I'm trying to compile a part of my thesis with tex4ht (to use LibreOffice grammar checker). It was working well few weeks ago but now it fails with the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\H@refstepcounter #1->\sf@Hrefstepcounter 
                                      {#1}\@ifundefined {c@sub#1}{}{\if@...
l.42  \centering
```

It seems related to the subfig package.

I use TeXLive 2010 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Here is MWE with the way I load hyperref (the photo is the one from this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein)):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,headsepline,headinclude,footinclude]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,breaklinks=false,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \subfloat[Who's that?]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Einstein_1921_portrait2.jpg}}%
 \qquad
 \subfloat[Who's that?]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Einstein_1921_portrait2.jpg}}
 \caption{A famous scientist and his twin brother.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. The error might be caused by loading **subfig** after **hyperref**. With a few exceptions, **hyperref** has to be loaded last, **subfig** is *not* among the exceptions.

Comment: Thanks but **subig** is loaded before **hyperref**.

Comment: So a minimal working example is needed.

Comment: I'm working on it :)

Comment: If I Remove **hyperref** and **hypcap** the document compiles.

Comment: I have tried to use [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/is-there-an-iftex4ht-command-and-if-not-how-should-it-be-defined) trick to load hyperref only for pdflatex and not tex4ht but I still have issues  when compiling my real document because it needs **hyperref**.

Comment: So I guess there is an option in hyperref that is incompatible with tex4ht. If you have some clue...

Comment: It seems that **hypcap** is responsible.

Comment: If I load **hyperref** without option, the error is `\caption@prepareslc ...tepcounter \measuring@true 
                                                  \let \caption@makeanchor \...
l.17 ...s[width=5cm]{Einstein_1921_portrait2.png}}
`

Comment: Thanks. I have used `\@ifpackageloaded` to avoid **hypcap** with tex4ht but now I'm facing: `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'Item' defined.`

Comment: Playing a bit more with `\@ifpackageloaded` I finally compiled my long document... which is invalid. Inspecting the xml files in the odt showed that some files are not correct. For instance style.xml did contain </xml>. I probably use too much tricks which finally confuse tex4ht.

Comment: Tex4ht is a cannon, and you're using it as a flyswatter. Here http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/mn.html is a list of software that can convert tex/latex to other formats (see "Resources"). I would suggest using something much simpler. BTW, I know you asked about grammar checking rather than spell checking, but for spell checking, ispell with the -t option works great.

Comment: The real document that I want to compile is much more complicated (> 100 pages) and the OO is sometime more convenient. Nevertheless you're right I could avoid TeX4HT.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see there are more than one problem.

1. As one can see in the log hyperref stopped early. This means that quite a lot commands are not defined. One of this now undefined commands is `\H@refstepcounter` and so the code of subfig

   ```
    \let\sf@Hrefstepcounter\H@refstepcounter
    \def\H@refstepcounter#1{%
   ```

   fails. That's probably easy to go around this by using `\makeatletter\let\H@refstepcounter\refstepcounter` in the preamble.
2. caption doesn't realize that hyperref has stopped early as it test for `\hyper@makecurrent` and the tex4ht style for hyperref (hyperref.4ht) defines it. So caption asume that commands exist (`measuring@true`) which are actually undefined.

I can't think about a sane way around this problem. In both cases I think that packages which use *internal* commands of other packages shouldn't assume they exist but actual test the existence - it is always possible that the names changes.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: I'm open for ideas on a better test if hyperref has stopped early or not. However, I will extend this test in future versions of the caption package.

Comment: @Axel: I would suggest that you ask Heiko to insert a clear marker, e.g. a switch `\hyp@stoppedearlytrue.

Comment: I changed the algorithm to test if hyperref has stopped early in caption v3.2 which is available on CTAN now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **subfig** and **hypcap** are not compatible with TeX4ht. If I load **subfigure** instead (changing `\subfloat` into `\subfigure`) and delete the call to **hypcap**, the document compiles.

Comment: I did some trick like that (see my comments above) but in the end the document is unusable. I think I will give up. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The `subfig` package usually loads the `caption` package. And if the `caption` package is loaded, the `hypcap` package isn't needed at all. (See caption package documentation for details.)

Comment: @Axel The document doesn't compile also when **hypcap** is not loaded.

Comment: Initially I started to use **subfig** because according to [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=6637) page **subfigure** is obsolete but I have just realized that **subfig** is considered obsolete too.