# what is the correct way to check for latex, pdflatex and html in the same latex document?

Tags: pdftex, tex4ht, latex2html

What is the correct way to check for if one is running in pdflatex vs latex vs. an html processor such as tex4ht?

Suppose I have some latex code that I only want to show up in html, and not show up in pdf and not show up in .ps.

Since tex4ht works in latex mode, then if I try this:

```
\ifpdf
  %  pdflatex code, do not show the link here
\else
  %  latex code
     \htmladdnormallink{home}{../../index.htm}
\fi
```

Then the above will show up the link ok when I run it by tex4ht, and will
not when I run it by pdflatex. But the problem is that the link will also show up when I run dvi2ps to generate .ps files.

if I use

```
\usepackage{html}
...
\begin{htmlonly}
   % html only code
\end{htmlonly}
```

to separate the html code, then tex4ht *does not understand the above*. I ended up with html pages where the code inside the above is missing !

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{ifpdf} 
\usepackage{html}
\usepackage{tex4ht} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{htmlonly}
\htmladdnormallink{home}{index.htm}
\end{htmlonly}

\end{document}
```

then

```
htlatex foo.tex
```

And there is no link shown in the generated html. Btw, htlatex does handle the `\htmladdnormallink` fine as I see the links fine when I remove `\begin{html}`. It just does not know about `\begin{html}`

tex4ht does not care about pdflatex mode, it seems to work in latex mode.

However the command

```
latex2html foo.tex
```

produces an html file with the link in there.

If I try this:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}%
 \usepackage{ifpdf} 
 \usepackage{html}
 \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}        

\ifpdf
        %  pdflatex code, do not show the link here
\else
      %  latex code
      \begin{htmlonly}
         \htmladdnormallink{home}{../../index.htm} 
      \end{htmlonly}
\fi

\end{document}
```

Then the same problem. ps does not show the link, which is what I want, but also the html file generated by tex4ht does not show the link!

So, I was trying to use tex4ht now instead of latex2html to generate html to try it out, but I also want to generate .pdf and .ps from the same document.

What is the correct way to do this in latex? in a way that tex4ht would understand as well.  Basically what I really want, is to have some code
that only used when generating html using tex4ht. Otherwise, I will just keep using latex2html if there is no way to do this.

**update**

This is the final setup, a complete self contained example that shows how to use the same latex file with pdflatex, latex/dvips and tex4ht.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{ifpdf} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\edef\texforht{TT\noexpand\fi
  \@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}
    {\noexpand\iftrue}
    {\noexpand\iffalse}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ifpdf
        I am in pdf mode %  pdflatex code,will show up in pdf only
\else
      %  latex code, check if htlatex is loaded and use link only then
      \if\texforht  
         \href{../../index.htm}{home} % show up in HTML only
      \else
       I am in latex mode %  shows up in dvi and .ps only but not in html
      \fi      
\fi

\end{document}
```

Now doing `htlatex foo.tex` and `pdflatex foo.tex` and `latex foo.tex` and `dvips foo.dvi` all work as expected. Only the foo.html will have the link shown.

thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5153/86 for ways to build a test for tex4ht.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, thanks, I looked at this link, and I tried to implement the solution there, but no luck. I added a note showing what I typed and the errors I get.

Comment: @Nasser You are loading `tex4ht` when trying to create a PDF: this sounds like a bad idea. Normally you don't load `tex4ht` yourself but leave that to `htlatex` (or similar).

Comment: @Nasser I would suggest you to use a private configuration file for tex4ht. See figure 6 in E.Gurari "TeX4ht: HTML Production" (http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb25-1/gurari.pdf). Macro \greetings has different definition for latex and for tex4ht.

Comment: @JosephWright, but this is like catch 20/20. I need to include `\usepackage{tex4ht}` so that I can use `\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}` as was suggested. I think this whole process is not leading any where. Instead of doing this by bits and pieces, may be someone can show a complete solution. Each one suggest to do something else, and a user like me ends up with many suggestions each conflicting with each others.

Comment: @Nasser No, you don't need `tex4ht` loaded to test for it: that is the entire point! If you do `\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}` and the package is not loaded then the test is false.

Comment: @JosephWright, Ok I understand now. thanks. I am learning text4ht, and number of examples (not all), say to include this package. actually the first example here `http://folk.uio.no/simek/document/document.pdf` uses it. Any way ;) I removed it, and now it worked. I will correct my example above now. Thanks.

Comment: @JosephWright if you please post this as answer, so I can accept it and have this closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you want to test for `tex4ht` using `\@ifpackagesloaded`, you do not want to load `tex4ht` in every job! This will interfere with the standard pdfLaTeX settings and make PDF creation more difficult. Instead, leave the package loading out (but include the test) and `htlatex` will make the necessary arrangements to load `tex4ht` when you are creating HTML files.

Comment: im getting `Warning: No implementation found for package: ifpdf` how can i proceed? running latex2html

Comment: @idgorman Please post a separate question about this: `ifpdf` is a standard package and is widely available.