# `\ifhtlatex` needed for running tex4ht with different code

Tags: conditionals, tex4ht, htlatex

It is much easier to write my texts in an editor with LaTeX, but often clients ask for a word file.

tex4ht does a good job, it produces html from a tex-file, which can be easily used. But there are some packages which cause errors, e.g. the §-sign of Linux Libertine. Is it possible to have a command which makes pdflatex have a look whether it is run by htlatex?

I'd like to write something like

```
 \ifhtlatex
\usepackage{lmodern}
\else 
\usepackage{libertine}
\fi
```

There are more things that don't work with htlatex, e.g. the machinery to name and count exhibitions and to produce a list of them at documents end. So something like `\ifhtlatex` would be helpfull.

==========

I dont't want to load the tex4ht package itself, so I've no idea, how this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93852/what-is-the-correct-way-to-check-for-latex-pdflatex-and-html-in-the-same-latex) could be helpfull...

Comment: You mean something beyond `\newif\ifhtlatex` etc.?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't want to check for html or pdflatex!

Comment: @jon No, I just have not idea how to detect whether htlatex called pdftex, or pdflatex.

Comment: @KeksDose `html` in that question meant `tex4ht` the answer being essentially to use `\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}` as the tex4ht script adds that package to your document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, I did not know that. So the difference to the related question here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93852/what-is-the-correct-way-to-check-for-latex-pdflatex-and-html-in-the-same-latex) is, that I just need to know tex4ht loaded or not, while there three options have to be checked.

Comment: @KeksDose see the updated code in the referenced question (which should have been in an answer) `\if\texforht  ` seems to be exactly what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`htlatex` loads package `tex4ht` via the hook `\@documentclasshook` that is called at the end of the document class. Thus you can test for this package *after* `\documentclass`:

```
\documentclass[...]{...}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifhtlatex
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{\htlatextrue}{\htlatexfalse}
\makeatother
```

*Before* `\documentclass` the macro `\HCode` could be checked that is defined by `htlatex`, e.g.:

```
\newif\ifhtlatex
\ifx\HCode\UnDeFiNeD
  \htlatexfalse
\else
  \htlatextrue
\fi
\documentclass{...}
```

Comment: Why `\UnDeFiNeD` with this capitalization?

Comment: @musarithmia It does not matter any undefined command will do. "Funny" names are less likely to be defined.