# Most useful/important (La)TeX commands/environments

Tags: environments, best-practices

A friend of mine asked me why I use `LaTeX` instead of Word/OpenOffice/LibreOffice etc. (no, this is not going to be a question like 'Word vs. LaTeX')

I showed him some of the showcases here on `TeX.SE`, some of my personal work too (not shown here). He was puzzled about the 'huge range of commands' to be learned. He wanted to know which and how many commands he should learn in order to produce 'reasonable' documents.

My answer was that this would depend on the type and content of the document, but I could not give a clear answer.

I know, this question might provoke opinion based answers or is too broad, therefore I want to restrict the question

> What are the 50 most useful/important commands or environments for
>   writing a typographically good every-day-document (article/book/beamer)?
>   Probably those commands/environments are the most used ones(?)

In order to reduce the wide range of possible answers I will put some more obstacles:

- Since a lot of `TeX` macros deal with mathematical typesetting, it's
  better to exclude them in this question, environments however are 'allowed'
- No `LaTeX` document can 'live' without `\documentclass` and `\document`, so those macros are mandatory anyway and can be excluded
- Environments `\begin{...}...\end{...}`  should count just as one command
- Class/Package writer commands and deep internals should be excluded too, as they have in principle nothing to do with everyday's work.
- TikZ/pstricks etc. are really nice bundles, but it's not useful to list a lot of macros from those packages
- Structuring commands like `\chapter` etc. are basically the same, so they count as one
- `\blindtext` `\lipsum` are not useful in producing everyday's document, so they do not count as well
- The various `\cite...` commands available from bibliographies count as one

I know, there are some (un)related questions

- [What are the most common mistakes that beginners of (La)TeX and Friends make?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139873/what-are-the-most-common-mistakes-that-beginners-of-latex-and-friends-makest)
- [How can I explain the meaning of LaTeX to my grandma?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94889/how-can-i-explain-the-meaning-of-latex-to-my-grandma/94897#94897)
- [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex)

### **It is not necessary to list exactly 50 macros or environments -- I will collect from the answers and generate a top list of them**

Comment: I think you should make clear whether you want to include commands which require packages or not. If you do, I think the question is too broad: there are too many possible answers. I'd suggest limiting it to a standard class with a short, fixed preamble - maybe just `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}`.

Comment: @cfr: Of course, packages provide a huge range of possible commands, but many of them reimplement `tabular`, for example

Comment: While a nice question, I think it's too broad and also too opinion based to be a worthwhile SE question. That said, would PGF's `\foreach` be too low-level for you? I have found this one (as a representative for similar commands) to be a [huge advantage](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/complete-graph/) over "non-programmable" tools.

Comment: @closevoters: This is not a duplicate of that linked question ;-)

Comment: It definitely is not a duplicate of that question. Whether it is too broad is a different matter. I could imagine it being thought too broad or, even, too opinion-based. But 'top 50 commands' cannot be thought equivalent to 'packages most often loaded by default'!

Comment: Actually, it's quite probable that in order to use *Word* or *LibreOffice*, the number of commands is larger: the number of buttons is overwhelming. It's really strange someone can work in such environment. I recently read someone had made a text-editor with no buttons (only shortcuts) simply to have some peace.

Comment: @CommuSoft: I remember such text-editors as well, in the early nineties... Wordstar etc. ;-)

Comment: Your second item says: "No document can 'live' without \documentclass`". Sorry, this is not true. I know many documents without `\documentclass` and all documents I produce is without this command. Your title puts "La" into brackets, so TeX itself is supposed too, IMHO.

Comment: @wipet: Yes, `TeX` commands but not pure PlainTeX source files ;-)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Note that I refuse to exclude essential commands and environments. A list of the most important should be just that: any list of specific macros which misses `\documentclass` and `document` is deficient! In fact, these are so important that they are numbered zero in the list below (as a kind of concession to sticklers for following the rules dictated in questions):

## **Two** + Fifty LaTeX Basics

[image: 2+50 commands and environments]

Note that 8 and 9 are not errors. In particular, the first disjunct of 8 is a blank line and 9 is a comment (essential for avoiding spurious spaces).

## Notes

- The emphasis here is on producing an article. As such, commands for contents listings, lists of figures, chapters etc. are omitted. (Except that contents stuff is useful for `beamer`. See below.)

  - Obviously, some people's first LaTeX document will be a multi-chapter creation. Mine was. But I don't think this is the best way to begin, and it is not a route I would recommend to the non-desperate. (I was desperate so I would recommend it to me. But that is not the standard case, I hope.)
- I've attempted to emphasise semantic mark-up as opposed to manual formatting. So `\textbf{}`, `\itshape`, `\small` etc. are out, whereas `\section` etc. are in.
- `\emph` is an exception in being halfway between semantic mark-up and manual formatting. However, insofar as it is the latter, it is essentially tied to content and is, therefore, the business of the document author and not the style author.

  - The writer of a class or package does not know which words I wish to, or ought to, emphasise!
- The list tries to illustrate some key concepts without presenting an exhaustive list, which cannot be done in 50 items and would be fairly useless to a beginner in any case.

  - 17 is there largely as an example of a character which is treated as special and so needs to be escaped. It is not the only character of this kind, of course, but it is the one I think I use most frequently.
  - 18 is there as an example of an accent. It happens to be the one I need most often.
- Regarding 23, at least in my discipline, `quotation` is more standard than `quote`. I only ever use the latter, really, by mistake or for a purpose it was not designed for.
- 27 and 28 are disjunctive because I think it does not matter terribly much which system you first learn to format citations and references with, provided you learn some form of semantic mark-up.

  - And it certainly would not be wise to learn multiple systems all at once! So the disjunctions here are necessary: the list ought not include commands for all three systems separately, as though a learner should immediately try to figure out the standard environment, BibTeX and BibLaTeX/Biber all at the same time.
- I am not sure I would encourage a beginner to typeset presentations using LaTeX, but I've included some items for `beamer` anyway.

  - `\includegraphics` is listed here because I think this much less basic with respect to other kinds of documents, whereas it is pretty essential when preparing slides.
- Letters were not mentioned in the question but are an extremely common, everyday kind of document to create, and knowing some basic commands and environments for making them seems appropriate.
- The exception for mathematical *environments* (as opposed to commands) was added after I'd disappeared to work on the list, and I therefore planned the list on the assumption that mathematical mark-up was to be excluded.

  - For me, personally, this is not unreasonable as I typeset relatively little mathematics.
  - However, for a standard list, I'd recommend cutting the `beamer` section and adding stuff for mathematics instead.
  - In any case, I would certainly cut 2 of the items here to make room for `$...$` and `\[...\]` which I do actually use a bit.

## Code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newcommand*\mycommand[2][command]{%
  \def\tempa{command}%
  \def\tempb{env}%
  \def\tempc{#1}%
  \ifx\tempa\tempc \item \texttt{\textbackslash #2}
  \else \item \texttt{\textbackslash begin\{#2\} \dots \textbackslash end\{#2\}}
  \fi}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{-1}
    \mycommand{documentclass}\setcounter{enumi}{-1}
    \mycommand[env]{document}
    \mycommand{usepackage}
    \mycommand{author}
    \mycommand{title}
    \mycommand{date}
    \mycommand{maketitle}
    \mycommand{section}
    \mycommand{subsection}
    \item \mbox{}\\\emph{or} \texttt{\textbackslash par}
    \item \texttt{\%}
    \mycommand[env]{enumerate}
    \mycommand[env]{itemize}
    \mycommand{item}
    \mycommand{emph}
    \item \texttt{\textquotesingle}
    \item \texttt{--}
    \item \texttt{---}
    \mycommand{\&}
    \mycommand{\textasciicircum}
    \mycommand{footnote}
    \mycommand{label}
    \mycommand{ref}
    \mycommand{cite}
    \mycommand[env]{quotation}
    \item \texttt{\textasciigrave\dots\textquotesingle}
    \item \texttt{\textasciigrave\textasciigrave\dots\textquotesingle\textquotesingle}
    \mycommand{dots}
    \mycommand[env]{thebibliography}\\\emph{or} \texttt{\textbackslash bibliography}\\\emph{or} \texttt{\textbackslash printbibliography}
    \mycommand{bibitem}\\\emph{or} \texttt{\textbackslash bibliographystyle}\\\emph{or} \texttt{\textbackslash usepackage[]\{biblatex\}}
    \mycommand[env]{abstract}
    \mycommand[env]{figure}
    \mycommand[env]{table}
    \mycommand{caption}
    \mycommand{centering}
    \mycommand[env]{tabular}
    \mycommand{hline}
    \item \texttt{\&}
    \item[\textbullet] \emph{for letters:}
    \mycommand[env]{letter}
    \mycommand{name}
    \mycommand{signature}
    \mycommand{opening}
    \mycommand{closing}
    \mycommand{encl}
    \item[\textbullet] \emph{for beamer:}
    \mycommand[env]{frame}
    \mycommand{titlepage}
    \mycommand{tableofcontents}
    \mycommand[env]{columns}
    \mycommand[env]{column}
    \mycommand[env]{block}
    \mycommand{usetheme}
    \mycommand{includegraphics}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Smart way to write your list. Suggestion: `\texttt{}` for commands?

Comment: @Sigur Yes, I should. It just always looks so ugly!

Comment: @cfr: `\documentclass` and `document` are the most important commands for sure, but they are implicit in 'my' list ;-)

Comment: So, my list is *deficient*?! lol I'd say that any list couldn't exist if we don't assume those 2 commands. lol

Comment: @Sigur: No, your list is not deficient.

Comment: @Sigur Only because the question was edited to exclude them while I was writing my list ;). Still, I refuse to exclude them. Answers should be useful to all users - even those who don't bother to read the questions!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer As a concession, I've numbered them zero in my final list, which also reflects their importance.

Comment: @cfr: ;-) Can't upvote again ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Stickler for the rules! I bet you insist on obeying the law of gravity even on public holidays, as well. ;)

Comment: since a blank line is equivalent to `\par`, why not offer both options in item 8?  (would be clear then -- at least to someone who knew some (la)tex -- without explanation.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was worried that might count as 2 commands, and I figured that leaving a blank line is more useful for beginners. (I used LaTeX for ages without knowing about `\par`. Not necessarily competently, but I did manage to make some paragraphs.) If Christian says I can have both, I would add it. (In other cases I've got either... or... but I guess a conjunct might be different.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I don't object to have them as two separate commands

Comment: @cfr: Very elaborate ... awesome

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you. I think I've been capped, too, as nobody told me about the 9th vote, I don't think. +50 for 9 votes :(.

Comment: +1, but I think you missed `\ifdefined\HCode...\fi` in your list. I use this more than anything else myself.

Comment: @Nasser Really? What does it do?

Comment: it is conditional to allow one to run some code in same latex file in pdflatex mode vs. tex4ht mode. [examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/is-there-an-iftex4ht-command-and-if-not-how-should-it-be-defined) I use it all the time, since my latex file has to compile both in pdf mode and tex4ht mode.

Comment: @Nasser Interesting. But I can't see putting it in the top 50. That is rather advanced usage! Note that these are not supposed to be the 50 commands you use most or, even, the ones people use most. I actually don't think the lists will be the same.

Comment: @Nasser There are commands on my list which I *never* use, but I still think are essential to have here. And there are commands I use all the time which are not included.

Comment: I would disagree with this list. Most people use LaTeX to typeset articles with mathematical formulas. However this list misses even `equation` env nothing to say about `gather`, `align`, `aligned`, etc,

Comment: I would favour `~` to `'`, since the latter is just a standard way how to write it in all editors, independently of LaTeX.

Comment: I would also include  `_{}` and `^{}`.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov As explained, I planned the list before the question was edited to allow mathematical environments.

Comment: @Guido Those are mathematical macros and explicitly excluded by the question.

Comment: @yo' I was thinking that it was not obvious that LaTeX would do 'the right thing' in this case. That is, as a beginner, you learn that you need to type special commands to achieve things which other programmes do automatically (e.g. type a back tick for an opening curly quotation mark) and that makes 'what command makes an apostrophe?' a reasonable question, I think.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov: I **excluded** the huge bunch of mathematical macros since this would pile up the list unnecessarily. Most of don't use all of math typesetting in a document, but it's very likely to have sections/enumerations etc.

Answer (score 14):

I am too lazy to make a list of 50 commands, but the [LaTeX cheet sheet](http://www.stdout.org/~winston/latex/) of Winston Chang, in a single page, cover a list of basic commands and even include a MWE. Very helpful for a novice.

If you do not agree completely with the selection, the LaTeX source file is available and you can modify under the terms of a CC license.

For a longer list, see the [AMS-LATEX Reference Card #1](http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/ReferenceCards/LaTeXRefCard.v2.0.pdf).

Finally, I think that the Beamer class probably deserves its own list of commands as well as themes, templates options, etc. The  [Beamer appearance cheet sheet](http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf).

Comment: Well, I stated in my question, that it's not necessary to list exactly 50 commands... I will collect from answers and generate a list of the top 50 commands

Answer (score 12):

Since I'm a mathematician, I would say:

1. sectional commands (`\section \subsection`)
2. `equation` environment (and their variants, e.g., `align`).
3. labels and refs for crossed references (`\label \eqref \cite`).
4. diagram packages (`xy tikz`)

and of course,

5. AMS packages/commands (e.g., `amsmath \DeclareMathOperator`).

Comment: (+1) I don't think this list is deficient. But I think mine would be deficient if I excluded those commands, just because we've answered at different levels of generality.

Answer (score 8):

'~' is indispensable to write a decent paper. This is due to the fact that using the tilde results in putting non-breakable space in a document. In consequence we may easily eliminate typesetting errors connected with breaking lines, the so called *orphans*, for example:

```
This is due to the fact that using the tilde 
results in putting non-breakable space in a 
document.
```

The linebreak after 'a' and before 'document' can be thus eliminated by typing 'a~document'.

Thus '~' is one of the (La)TeX goodies really worth mastering. And according to Knuth himself via this you can gain a lot:

Once you learn how to insert them [i.e. '~'s], you will have graduated from
the ranks of ordinary TeXnical typists to the select group of Distinguished
TeXnicians. (TeXbook, p. 91)

Comment: perhaps it might be good to explain why '~' is so useful

Comment: @samcarter Good point. Improved my answer.