# extra \fi error when using \localtableofcontents inside an \if...\else..\fi

Tags: tocloft, etoc

When I put `\localtableofcontents` (which comes from one of these pacakges `tocloft` or `etoc`), inside the `\if....\else..\fi` then I get an error.

The reason I wanted to put it inside an `if` is because I want the file to compile both with tex4ht and pdflatex, and I do not want this when running in tex4ht mode.

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{report}

\ifdefined\HCode
\else
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoc}
\fi

\begin{document}
\chapter{ my chapter }

\ifdefined\HCode
\else
\localtableofcontents %this gives the error
\fi

\end{document}
```

now pdflatex foo.tex gives

```
>pdflatex foo.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
....
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tocloft/tocloft.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoc/etoc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty)) (./foo.aux)
Chapter 1.
! Extra \fi.
<recently read> \fi 

l.15 \fi
```

How would I prevent \localtableofcontents from being used in tex4ht mode if I can't exclude it using `\ifdefined\HCode` logic?

```
>pdflatex foo.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
```

File list:

```
*File List*
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 tocloft.sty    2013/05/02 v2.3f parameterised ToC, etc., typesetting
    etoc.sty    2014/04/22 v1.07l Completely customisable TOCs (jfB)
multicol.sty    2014/10/28 v1.8i multicolumn formatting (FMi)
```

Comment: I have added something to my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/is-there-an-iftex4ht-command-and-if-not-how-should-it-be-defined

Comment: @egreg thank you. I looked at it and will study it more.

Comment: just for people reading this question in the future: `\localtableofcontents` indeed comes from `etoc`, not `tocloft`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why, but it seems an expansion problem.

Adding `\expandafter` before `\localtableofcontents` solves the issue.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{report}

\ifdefined\HCode
\else
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoc}
\fi

\begin{document}
\chapter{ my chapter }

\ifdefined\HCode
\else
\expandafter\localtableofcontents %no error
\fi

\end{document}
```

Output (PDFLaTeX)

[image]

As an alternative, as suggested by jfbu, you can load the `etoolbox` package and use `\ifdef` instead of `\ifdefined` in the following way

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ifdef{\HCode}{}{%
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\usepackage{etoc}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ my chapter }

\ifdef{\HCode}{}{%
\localtableofcontents%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, nice workaround. I confirmed it works ok on my end.

Comment: `etoc`'s `\tableofcontents` and `\localtableofcontents` both fetch using `\futurelet` the token coming next, to implement its `\label/\ref` mechanism. If this token is a `\fi` then a problem arises due to the peculiarities of `TeX`'s `\if..\else..\fi`mechanism. With `\expandafter` the problem indeed is solved. A recommended alternative is to load package `etoolbox` and use (in the context of the OP's question) `\ifdef{\HCode}{}{\localtableofcontents}` instead.